# Open C# webserver in local wlan

Tags: c#, webserver, lan, httplistener, wifi

I made a simple http-listener in C#. It currently connects to the Prefix "http://*:5080/index/". How do I make it accessible in the local wlan network. Like, how can I connect it to other devices in the wlan network?

Comment: `*` means 'bind listener to all interfaces' I believe. Therefore you already should be listening on that interface. I suspect a firewall might need a tweak?

Comment: Deactivating the firewall (on both devices) didn't change anything @timur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same problem and I solve it by these steps

1- make static Ip for your project like 127.0.0.1:5080/index

2- if you want to use in another case you must be make this port (5080 in this example )  safe for firewall but 80 or 8080 don't need

3- if you want use your project online on web or internet you must be take IpStatic from your ISP(internet service provider) and create port forwarding in your router

I hope it will help you